2 functions are not isotopic
General question: In general, what methods do we have for showing 2 functions $f:X\to Y$ are not isotopic (i.e homotopic s.t each $H(*,t)$ is a homeomorphism$:X\to H(X,t)$ for every $t$)
specific problem: if $f:S^{1}\to\mathbb{C},g:S^{1}\to\mathbb{C}$. And $f(s)=s,g(s)=\bar{s}$. prove/disprove they aren't isotopic.
I feel like they aren't isotopic and the proof would be to show that for any homotopy $H$ between $f$ and $g$, $H(*,t)$ isn't injective for some $t\in[0,1]$ and then this cannot be a homeomorphism between $S^1$ and $H(S^1,t)$. But how can one show this formally?

Hint: What are the degrees of $f$ and $g$, understood as maps $S^1 \to S^1$?

Can you clarify what do you mean by degree? Also, I'm looking for a formal explanation - I can already intuitively see why one cannot deform the loop into the reversed loop without intersecting itself.

The degree of a map $f\colon S^1 \to S^1$ is the unique integer $\operatorname{deg}(f)$ such that $f_*(\iota) = \operatorname{deg}(f) \cdot \iota$ where $\iota \in \pi_1(S^1)$ is a generator; you should be able to find this in any standard algebraic topology textbook, e.g. Hatcher's. The hint is not meant to give you more intuition but a formal tool (a homotopy invariant, namely) you can use to build a proof on.

Sorry for misunderstanding I'm not yet familiar with homology, if I'm understanding correctly in the case of $S^1$ this is simply the winding number, correct? If so, do you have a more elementary proof why 2 loops with different winding numbers are not isotopic?

It is the winding number, yes. This is about the fundamental group, not homology; the proof that two homotopic maps have the same degree/winding number is the same that $f_*$ is a group homomorphism: If you have two loops and a homotopy between them, then composing the homotopy with $f$ gives a homotopy between the loops composed with $f$ (assuming that $f$ preserves the basepoint). You could also use the characterization of the winding number via contour integrals from complex analysis paired with the fact that every continuous curve is homotopic to a smooth one if this is more familiar.

But the claim is true only for isotopy not homotopy. For homotopy one can take the point-wise homotopy from $f$ to $g$ so they are homotopic (the map could be from $S^1$ to all of $\mathbb{C}$). The reason it fails for isotopy is because this points-wise homotopy is not homeomorphic at $t=0.5$ (it's not even injective). Maybe you are answering a different problem?

I think you were trying to answer why on $S^1$ one cannot deform a loop with some winding number to another loop with another winding number. I am talking about all of $\mathbb{C}$

Since you are unfamiliar with homology, you simply do not have enough tools to solve this problem. It is a bit easier if you work in the smooth category but in the topological category you would be using Schoenflies theorem and homological definition of orientation (and much more). Why are you trying to solve this problem?

Our professor gave us this as an exercise after defining isotopy, but come to think of it, it seems like he didn't expect us to rigorously solve it. At any rate, I should probably consider studying homology anyway. thanks for the support :)

@ChrisP.Bacon I was giving you a hint that being unable to do that on $S^1$ might be related to being unable to do that in $\mathbb{C}$ via an isotopy :)
